# Set EditText to have phone number values set

Tags: android, android-edittext, string-formatting, phonenumberutils

I have been trying to have my editText accept phone values only as well as extensions. I managed to do this in its xml phone using.

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789()- x"
```

Now the other problem I have been attempting to figure out is how to have editText display (  )    -     at all times and when more numbers pressed (ooo) ooo-oooo xoooo.  Currently I have editText

```
editTextpponentTeamContactPhone.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() {
PhoneNumberUtils phoneNumberUtils;

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            phoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(editTextpponentTeamContactPhone.getText().toString());
            super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        }
    });
```

This is close to what I want.  It becomes (xxx) xxx-xxxx but not extensions so was wondering if anyone had come through something similar I am looking but not getting much luck.

Answer (score 0):

To limit char lenght at `TextView` you can use

```
android:maxLength="14"
```

or programmatically :

```
textView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(250) });
```

Comment: Well that is something that I am doing already, but the issue isn't with length.  It's about showing at all times (   )   -      or     (    )    -       x.  I can modify the string but am trying to force this format in editext.

Comment: @AshleyAlvarado well, you can write a custom TextWatcher that will be listen your edit text changes after input text. When text.isEmpty - clean up all text view content.